# mac os 10.6.2 installation error

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

when I installing mac os , Every icon is showing .app extension.

Comment: Also flagged this for migration to apple.stackexchange.com as it seems better suited to there.

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting in the Finder to show extensions. Select the Finder, then go to from the menubar "Finder" > "Preferences", then click the advanced tab. The checkbox "Show all file extensions" is usually deselected by default, having it selected will cause the Finder to always show files with extensions such as `Firefox.app` or `Readme.pdf`. Unchecking this box makes the Finder try to keep this abstracted from you, listing things such as `Firefox` or `Readme`. I'd guess that this is checked for you?

Comment: This of course is only the answer if he means that "every icon [for each of my applications] is showing .app extension." However, I would also assume that's the case.